# Why won't chmod +s allow me to do stuff in root's stead?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have a very specific command I'd like anyone to be able to run. For the sake of example, let's pretend the command is `ip addr flush dev foo0`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717115/1735458) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191058/1735458). Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think it's exactly what I need.

```
echo "ip addr flush dev vboxnet0" > script.sh
chmod +x script.sh

chmod +s script.sh
sudo chown root script.sh
sudo chgrp root script.sh
```

But then,

```
./script.sh
Failed to send flush request: Operation not permitted
```

Why?

Comment: suid does not take effect on scripts.

Comment: @adonis Oh, bummer. Well, is that not the answer? Why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: imo, 1 line answers are not that good. I'll have to find relevant links to provide and think about how to be clear, etc. A comment seems easier sometimes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across this situation some weeks back and found this in the course of my research.  Perhaps it will help you as well.

https://superuser.com/a/636800